# Google App Engine with Android Bitmap class

Tags: java, android, image, google-app-engine, serialization

I have an Android application and a Google App Engine app communicating with each other.

The Android needs to send a Bitmap object to the Google App Engine. However, when I receive the Bitmap object on the cloud, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:33)
```

I have the Android jar in the appropriate lib file for Google App Projects. I don't know what am I missing and why this is happening, because with the same code, I can do the deserialization just fine within Android environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're serializing the data using Java's built in serialization support. Deserializing data in this way requires having the class definitions for the serialized object available, which obviously isn't the case on App Engine.

Instead, you should encode the bitmap in a standard format, such as PNG, and decode it as you would any other image on the App Engine end.